# Using async/await or then in typescript (React-Native) but not getting any result

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native

Here is code block where i am calling an axios call and promise is not resolving.
I am using typescript here , version of typescript is 4

````
getBalance = async (address: string) => {
      let endpoints = this.getBalanceEndpoint();
      for (let i = 0; i < endpoints.length; i++) {
        let endpoint = endpoints[i];
        const url = endpoint + address + '?details=basic';
        const param: object = {
          method: 'get',
          url: url,
          headers: {
            'User-Agent': UA,
          },
          timeout: 1000,
        };
        try {
          console.log(param,"Balance Params")
          **const response = await axios(param)**;
          console.log(response,"BITCOIN BALANCE")
          }
        } catch (e) {
          console.log(e)
        }
        await new Promise(resolve =>
          setTimeout(resolve, GENERIC_REQUEST_THROTTLE_DELAY)
        );
      }
      throw new Error('Unable to retrieve balance!');
    };
  ```

I am not getting any result or promise is not resolving in await axios call.

Please let me know answer
````

Comment: What does happen when you run this?

Comment: Not getting anything in console and code is not moving to next step when i am removing await then it showing me some kind of Promise object like this 

Promise {sletwty:0,onerror:null}

Comment: Can you show/explain the request made in your network devtools?

Comment: Sorry but not getting anything in network devtools, in console only it's showing me Promise or nothing

Comment: Please post links or files that reproduce the issue. This isn't enough information.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to return your responses from async function and to do some code changes:

```js
getBalance = async (address: string) => {
      let endpoints = this.getBalanceEndpoint();
      const result = []; // <-- create an RESULT variable
      for (let i = 0; i < endpoints.length; i++) {
        let endpoint = endpoints[i];
        const url = endpoint + address + '?details=basic';
        const param: object = {
          method: 'get',
          url: url,
          headers: {
            'User-Agent': UA,
          },
          timeout: 1000,
        };
        try {
          console.log(param,"Balance Params")
          const response = await axios(param); // <-- without **
          console.log(response,"BITCOIN BALANCE");
          result.push(response); // <-- add your response to result
        } catch (e) {
          console.log(e);
          throw new Error('Unable to retrieve balance!'); //<-- here it should be if you want to create your own error
        }
        await new Promise(resolve =>
          setTimeout(resolve, GENERIC_REQUEST_THROTTLE_DELAY)
        );
      }
      
      return result; // <-- return result to get it from the outside
    };
```

and don't forget about catching errors from the outside

```js
try {
  const mResponses = await getBalance(mAddress);
} catch (e) {
  console.log(e);
}
```